# EF6 Updating Code First Model from the Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I inherited an ASP.NET MVC application using Entity Framework 6.2.  The application was originally built using Code First and I can see migrations that have been applied to the database.  The structure of the database seems accurate.

However, a ton of relationships have been added to fix referential integrity issues and these were done directly on the database.  There are a bunch of them. Can someone help me to update the models from the database in a code first implementation?  Ideally it would remain code first, not a conversion, but I need to do a one time update.

I'm more familiar with newer EF Core and I thought it would as easy as running a scaffold-dbcontext command with a -force and some cleanup.  But no such luck in this older version.  Is there something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what a 'ton' means and whether you need to keep the old migrations you could either just rebuild the entire model by doing [code first from existing database](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-from-existing-database.aspx) or you could save the generated code into a folder and do a manual reconstruction:

1. Run code first from existing database into a new folder.
2. Map new fields and navigation properties into existing models.
3. Fix up any fluent code (modelBuilder).
4. Generate a migration which should include those changes.
5. A good test would be restoring a pre-change version of the database and running the migration against it. Then perhaps use a schema compare utility.
6. Apply the migration to databases. If the database already includes the changes, comment out the Up() code before applying. This will update the stored model so the next migration does not repeat these changes.